# Rails ParameterMissing error on create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When I try to create a user, Rails returns a ParameterMissing error:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in UserController#create
param is missing or the value is empty: user
```

My Controller

```
class UserController < ApplicationController

def create      
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  render json: @user
end

private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:fame, :lame, :mobile)
  end
end
```

My User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "user"
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please provide the form code?

Comment: I don't have form I will use it as api for my application

Answer (score 2):

Check your logs for the params that are being sent to your controller. Most likely, the params hash being sent by your view doesn't include the `:user`, key. To fix, you'll need to make sure your `form_for` is properly namespaced with a User object:

```
form_for @user do |f|
   # ...
end
```

You can also use the `as` key to explicitly set the `:user` key in your params.

```
form_for @object, as: :user, method: :post do |f|
   # ...
end
```

---

**Update**

Since the questioner was using `postman` to send data, the data sent to the server should be properly formatted like so:

```
user[firstName]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Thanks**  @Fabio and @Anthony
When you asked about the form, I actually realized that the parameter I sending with postman was actually incorrect as they should be like 
`user[firstName]`

**Updated**
It actually deepns upon you how you send the params.
I send as

`user[firstname]`  So I get like `params[:user][:firstName]` 
 If I send like `firstname` So this will be `params[:firstName]`